# Regex, PHP: assigning matches to an array after inserting expanded words

Tags: php, regex

Regex, PHP: assigning matches to an array after inserting expanded words

In a system that matches user input against a regex pattern I allow the pattern to contain "concept words" that are marked by a twiddle (~).
E.g. I can define

```
~service-type as '"oil change" rotation brake "tune up"' and 
~day as 'Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday'
```

I can then have a pre-regex like:

```
.*get.*~service-type.*~day
```

Which by some preprocessing gets expanded to:

```
/.*get.*(oil change|rotation|brake|tune up).*(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday)/i
```

So it will match a sentence like: "I'd like to get an oil change on Wednesday."

This gives me a nice $matches array that looks like this:

```
array
  0 => string 'I'd like to get an oil change on Wednesday' (length=42)
  1 => string 'oil change' (length=10)
  2 => string 'Wednesday' (length=9)
```

The difficulty now arises that it is possible or sometimes necessary that the regex contains other (...) patterns.
In this example I wouldn't really need it, but it shows the point:

```
(.*)(get).*~service-type(.*)~day
expands to
/(.*)(get).*(oil change|rotation|brake|tune up)(.*)(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday)/i
```

which results in $matches being:

```
array
  0 => string 'I'd like to get an oil change on Wednesday' (length=42)
  1 => string 'I'd like to ' (length=12)
  2 => string 'get' (length=3)
  3 => string 'oil change' (length=10)
  4 => string ' on ' (length=4)
  5 => string 'Wednesday' (length=9)
```

What I'm looking for is a quick and elegant way that would allow me in either case to generate some array like:

```
array
  'service-type' => string 'oil change' (length=10)
  'day' => string 'Wednesday' (length=9)
```

With elegant I mean I don't have to parse the pattern myself to find out how many and at which locations there are already (...) patterns and where I inserted the expanded concept words. If there's no better way please tell me too, than I can stop agonizing whether there is a nice way and bite the bullet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like something you could achieve using named patterns in your regex. See https://www.php.net/preg_match#example-4885

Comment: This was exactly what I needed after I got the syntax right and figured that I need to change the naming for concept-words only to allow [_A-z0-9]+, but not '-' any more. thanks